# Core Audio Tutorial Import-Lines

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-audio, header-files

I found the following tutorial for Core Audio:
http://prasadiphonecode.blogspot.de/2012/09/recording-voice-audio-in-iphone.html

But what has to be imported in the first three lines there?

Because it's just mentioned: '#import' without anything else

Thx!

btw: anyone out there who knows this tutorial and where to find it's code/Xcode-project to download?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioFile.h>
```

And for more help(in case of any confusion).. you may have a look on these following links :

[http://prassan-warrior.blogspot.in/2012/11/recording-audio-on-iphone-with.html](http://www.raywenderlich.com/259/audio-101-for-iphone-developers-playing-audio-programmatically)

http://www.raywenderlich.com/259/audio-101-for-iphone-developers-playing-audio-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

This are the 3 Required Frameworks for it, add to your project

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioQueue.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioFile.h>
```